# how to get the distance by `elasticsearch5.2` without `sort`?

Tags: elasticsearch

Q is how to get the distance by `elasticsearch5.2` without `sort`?

here is the mapping(model named 'service_point'):

```
{
  "service_point": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "type": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "ngram_tokenizer_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "ngram_tokenizer_analyzer"
      },
      "location": {
        "type": "geo_point"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

assumed that my location is :`{"lat":"31.182024","lon":"121.492417"}`
and,  I want to search a place named 'West Lake'. and want to get the distance between my location and 'West Lake'? how to get the distance?

this is my script, found the place within the distance `100KM` and named 'West Lake', but I can not get the distance between my location and 'West Lake'? how to get the distance.

```
{
  "from": "0",
  "size": "100",
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "location": {
              "lat": "31.182024",
              "lon": "121.492417"
            },
            "distance": "100km"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "name": "West Lake"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to make it clear, do you want to have the distance between your point and the one of the document returned by ElasticSearch, in the response?

Comment: yes, I want to get the distance in the response without use sort.